# Subversion (svn) doesn't store passwords in gnome-keyring

Tags: arch-linux, password, subversion, gnome-keyring

I fight with svn since 2 hours to store my password inside the gnome keyring, but nothing worked. 
I'm on a fresh installed archlinux system with the following packages installed:

```
acl 2.2.52-1
alsa-lib 1.0.27.2-1
alsa-utils 1.0.27.2-1
apr 1.4.8-1
apr-util 1.5.2-1
arandr 0.1.7.1-1
archlinux-keyring 20130818-1
aspell 0.60.6.1-1
at-spi2-atk 2.8.1-1
at-spi2-core 2.8.0-1
atk 2.8.0-1
attr 2.4.47-1
aurvote 1.5-2
autoconf 2.69-1
automake 1.14-1
avahi 0.6.31-10
bash 4.2.045-5
binutils 2.23.2-3
bison 3.0-1
boost-libs 1.54.0-3
bzip2 1.0.6-4
ca-certificates 20130610-1
ca-certificates-java 20130815-1
cairo 1.12.16-1
cdparanoia 10.2-4
chromium 29.0.1547.65-1
cloog 0.18.0-2
clucene 2.3.3.4-7
colord 1.0.2-2
compositeproto 0.4.2-2
coreutils 8.21-2
cracklib 2.9.0-1
cronie 1.4.9-5
cryptsetup 1.6.2-1
curl 7.32.0-1
customizepkg 0.2.1-2
damageproto 1.2.1-2
db 5.3.21-1
dbus 1.6.12-1
dbus-glib 0.100.2-1
dconf 0.16.1-1
desktop-file-utils 0.21-1
device-mapper 2.02.100-1
dhcpcd 6.0.5-1
dialog 1.2_20130523-2
diffutils 3.3-1
dirmngr 1.1.1-1
dnssec-anchors 20130320-1
dotconf 1.3-3
e2fsprogs 1.42.8-1
elfutils 0.155-1
enca 1.14-1
enchant 1.6.0-4
exo 0.10.2-1
expat 2.1.0-2
faac 1.28-4
faad2 2.7-3
fakeroot 1.19-1
farstream-0.1 0.1.2-2
fftw 3.3.3-1
file 5.14-1
filesystem 2013.05-2
findutils 4.4.2-5
firefox 23.0.1-1
fixesproto 5.0-2
flac 1.3.0-1
flashplugin 11.2.202.297-1
flex 2.5.37-1
fontconfig 2.10.95-1
fontsproto 2.1.2-1
freeglut 2.8.1-1
freetype2 2.5.0.1-1
fribidi 0.19.5-1
garcon 0.2.1-1
gawk 4.1.0-1
gcc 4.8.1-3
gcc-libs 4.8.1-3
gconf 3.2.6-2
gcr 3.8.2-1
gdbm 1.10-1
gdk-pixbuf2 2.28.2-1
gettext 0.18.3.1-1
giflib 5.0.4-2
git 1.8.4-1
glib-networking 2.36.2-1
glib2 2.36.4-1
glibc 2.18-3
glu 9.0.0-2
gmp 5.1.2-1
gnome-icon-theme 3.8.3-1
gnome-icon-theme-symbolic 3.8.3-1
gnome-keyring 3.8.2-1
gnupg 2.0.21-1
gnutls 3.2.4-1
gpgme 1.4.3-1
gpm 1.20.7-3
graphite 1:1.2.3-1
grep 2.14-2
grml-zsh-config 0.8.2-1
groff 1.22.2-5
grub 2.00.5086-1
gsettings-desktop-schemas 3.8.2-1
gsm 1.0.13-7
gstreamer0.10 0.10.36-2
gstreamer0.10-bad 0.10.23-4
gstreamer0.10-bad-plugins 0.10.23-4
gstreamer0.10-base 0.10.36-1
gstreamer0.10-base-plugins 0.10.36-1
gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg 0.10.13-1
gstreamer0.10-good 0.10.31-3
gtk-engines 2.21.0-1
gtk-update-icon-cache 2.24.20-1
gtk2 2.24.20-1
gtk2-xfce-engine 3.0.1-1
gtk3 3.8.4-1
gtk3-xfce-engine 3.0.1-1
gtkspell 2.0.16-2
gzip 1.6-1
harfbuzz 0.9.19-1
harfbuzz-icu 0.9.19-1
heirloom-mailx 12.5-3
hicolor-icon-theme 0.12-2
hspell 1.2-1
hunspell 1.3.2-2
hwids 20130607-1
hyphen 2.8.6-1
iana-etc 2.30-3
icon-naming-utils 0.8.90-2
icu 51.2-1
inetutils 1.9.1-6
inputproto 2.3-1
intel-dri 9.2.0-1
iproute2 3.10.0-1
iptables 1.4.19.1-1
iputils 20121221-3
isl 0.12.1-1
iso-codes 3.44-1
jasper 1.900.1-8
jdk7-openjdk 7.u40_2.4.1-3
jfsutils 1.1.15-4
jre7-openjdk 7.u40_2.4.1-3
jre7-openjdk-headless 7.u40_2.4.1-3
js 17.0.0-1
json-c 0.11-1
kbd 2.0.0-1
kbproto 1.0.6-1
keyutils 1.5.5-5
kmod 15-1
krb5 1.11.3-1
ladspa 1.13-4
lcms2 2.5-1
ldns 1.6.16-1
less 458-1
lib32-gcc-libs 4.8.1-3
lib32-glibc 2.18-3
lib32-libstdc++5 3.3.6-6
lib32-ncurses 5.9-2
lib32-zlib 1.2.8-1
libarchive 3.1.2-2
libass 0.10.1-1
libassuan 2.1.1-1
libasyncns 0.8-4
libatasmart 0.19-2
libcap 2.22-5
libcap-ng 0.7.3-1
libcdaudio 0.99.12-6
libcroco 0.6.8-1
libcups 1.6.3-1
libdaemon 0.14-2
libdatrie 0.2.6-1
libdc1394 2.2.1-1
libdca 0.0.5-3
libdrm 2.4.46-2
libdv 1.0.0-4
libdvdnav 4.2.0-2
libdvdread 4.2.0-1
libedit 20130601_3.1-1
libevent 2.0.21-2
libexif 0.6.21-1
libffi 3.0.13-3
libfontenc 1.1.2-1
libgcrypt 1.5.3-1
libglade 2.6.4-3
libgme 0.6.0-2
libgpg-error 1.12-1
libgssglue 0.4-1
libgusb 0.1.6-1
libice 1.0.8-1
libidn 1.26-1
libimobiledevice 1.1.5-1
libjpeg-turbo 1.3.0-2
libksba 1.3.0-1
libldap 2.4.35-4
liblrdf 0.5.0-1
libltdl 2.4.2-10
libmbim 1.4.0-1
libmms 0.6.2-1
libmng 2.0.2-2
libmodplug 0.8.8.4-1
libmp4v2 2.0.0-2
libmpc 1.0.1-1
libmpcdec 1.2.6-3
libnice 0.1.4-1
libnl 3.2.22-1
libnotify 0.7.5-1
libofa 0.9.3-4
libogg 1.3.1-1
libpcap 1.4.0-1
libpciaccess 0.13.2-1
libpipeline 1.2.4-1
libplist 1.10-1
libpng 1.6.3-1
libproxy 0.4.11-2
libpulse 4.0-2
libpurple 2.10.7-4
libqmi 1.4.0-2
libraw1394 2.1.0-1
libreoffice-af 4.1.1-1
libreoffice-base 4.1.1-2
libreoffice-calc 4.1.1-2
libreoffice-common 4.1.1-2
libreoffice-draw 4.1.1-2
libreoffice-gnome 4.1.1-2
libreoffice-impress 4.1.1-2
libreoffice-math 4.1.1-2
libreoffice-postgresql-connector 4.1.1-2
libreoffice-sdk 4.1.1-2
libreoffice-sdk-doc 4.1.1-2
libreoffice-writer 4.1.1-2
librsvg 1:2.37.0-1
libsamplerate 0.1.8-2
libsasl 2.1.26-4
libsecret 0.15-2
libsm 1.2.1-1
libsndfile 1.0.25-2
libsoup 2.42.2-1
libssh2 1.4.3-1
libtasn1 3.3-1
libthai 0.1.19-1
libtheora 1.1.1-3
libtiff 4.0.3-3
libtirpc 0.2.3-1
libtool 2.4.2-10
libunique 1.1.6-5
libusbx 1.0.16-2
libvdpau 0.7-1
libvisual 0.4.0-4
libvorbis 1.3.3-1
libvpx 1.2.0-1
libwebp 0.3.1-3
libwnck 2.30.7-1
libwpd 0.9.9-1
libwps 0.2.9-1
libx11 1.6.1-1
libxau 1.0.8-1
libxcb 1.9.1-2
libxcomposite 0.4.4-1
libxcursor 1.1.14-1
libxdamage 1.1.4-1
libxdmcp 1.1.1-1
libxext 1.3.2-1
libxfce4ui 4.10.0-1
libxfce4util 4.10.1-2
libxfixes 5.0.1-1
libxfont 1.4.6-1
libxft 2.3.1-1
libxi 1.7.2-1
libxinerama 1.1.3-1
libxkbcommon 0.3.1-1
libxkbfile 1.0.8-1
libxklavier 5.3-1
libxml2 2.9.1-2
libxmu 1.1.1-1
libxpm 3.5.10-1
libxrandr 1.4.1-1
libxrender 0.9.8-1
libxres 1.0.7-1
libxslt 1.1.28-1
libxss 1.2.2-1
libxt 1.1.4-1
libxtst 1.2.2-1
libxv 1.0.9-1
libxvmc 1.0.8-1
libxxf86vm 1.1.3-1
libzeitgeist 0.3.18-3
licenses 20130203-1
linux 3.10.10-1
linux-api-headers 3.10.6-1
linux-firmware 20130725-1
llvm-libs 3.3-1
logrotate 3.8.6-1
lpsolve 5.5.2.0-2
lsb-release 1.4-13
lsof 4.87-2
lvm2 2.02.100-1
lzo2 2.06-1
m4 1.4.16-3
make 3.82-6
man-db 2.6.5-1
man-pages 3.53-1
mcpp 2.7.2-4
mdadm 3.2.6-4
mesa 9.2.0-1
mesa-libgl 9.2.0-1
mime-types 9-1
mjpegtools 2.0.0-3
mkinitcpio 0.15.0-1
mkinitcpio-busybox 1.21.1-2
modemmanager 1.0.0-1
mozilla-common 1.4-3
mpfr 3.1.2-1
mtdev 1.1.3-1
mumble 1.2.4-2
musicbrainz 2.1.5-5
nano 2.2.6-2
ncurses 5.9-5
neon 0.29.6-4
net-tools 1.60.20130531git-1
netctl 1.3-1
nettle 2.7.1-1
networkmanager 0.9.8.2-1
nspr 4.10-2
nss 3.15.1-1
openjpeg 1.5.1-1
openresolv 3.5.6-1
openssh 6.2p2-1
openssl 1.0.1.e-3
opus 1.0.3-1
orc 0.4.17-1
p11-kit 0.18.4-1
package-query 1.2-2
pacman 4.1.2-1
pacman-mirrorlist 20130830-1
pam 1.1.6-4
pambase 20130113-1
pango 1.34.1-1
parted 3.1-2
patch 2.7.1-2
pciutils 3.2.0-3
pcmciautils 018-7
pcre 8.33-1
perl 5.18.1-1
perl-error 0.17021-1
perl-xml-parser 2.41-4
perl-xml-simple 2.20-1
pidgin 2.10.7-4
pinentry 0.8.3-1
pixman 0.30.2-1
pkg-config 0.28-1
pm-quirks 0.20100619-3
pm-utils 1.4.1-6
polkit 0.111-1
poppler 0.24.1-1
popt 1.16-6
postgresql-libs 9.2.4-2
ppp 2.4.5-8
procps-ng 3.3.8-2
protobuf 2.5.0-3
psmisc 22.20-1
pth 2.0.7-4
pygobject2-devel 2.28.6-9
pygtk 2.24.0-3
python 3.3.2-1
python-xdg 0.25-1
python2 2.7.5-1
python2-cairo 1.10.0-1
python2-gobject2 2.28.6-9
qt4 4.8.5-2
randrproto 1.4.0-1
raptor 2.0.9-2
rasqal 1:0.9.30-1
readline 6.2.004-1
recode 3.6-7
recordproto 1.14.2-1
redland 1:1.0.16-2
reiserfsprogs 3.6.24-1
renderproto 0.11.1-2
rsync 3.0.9-6
rtmpdump 20121230-2
run-parts 4.4-1
schroedinger 1.0.11-1
scrnsaverproto 1.2.2-1
sdl 1.2.15-3
seahorse 3.8.2-1
sed 4.2.2-3
serf 1.3.0-1
sg3_utils 1.36-1
shadow 4.1.5.1-6
shared-color-profiles 0.1.5-1
shared-mime-info 1.1-1
slim 1.3.5-3
snappy 1.1.0-1
soundtouch 1.7.1-1
speech-dispatcher 0.8-1
speex 1.2rc1-3
sqlite 3.8.0.1-1
startup-notification 0.12-3
strace 4.8-1
subversion 1.8.1-2
sudo 1.8.7-1
sysfsutils 2.1.0-8
systemd 204-3
systemd-sysvcompat 204-3
sysvinit-tools 2.88-11
tar 1.26-4
texinfo 5.1-1
thunar 1.6.3-1
thunar-volman 0.8.0-1
thunderbird 17.0.8-1
tmux 1.8-1
ttf-bitstream-vera 1.10-9
tumbler 0.1.29-1
tzdata 2013d-1
udisks 1.0.4-8
unixodbc 2.3.1-1
upower 0.9.20-2
usbmuxd 1.0.8-2
usbutils 007-1
util-linux 2.23.2-1
vi 1:050325-3
videoproto 2.3.2-1
vim 7.4.0-2
vim-runtime 7.4.0-2
vte 0.28.2-3
vte-common 0.34.7-1
wayland 1.2.1-1
wget 1.14-2
which 2.20-6
wildmidi 0.2.3.5-2
wpa_supplicant 2.0-4
xcb-proto 1.8-2
xcb-util 0.3.9-1
xdg-utils 1.1.0.git20130520-1
xextproto 7.2.1-1
xf86-input-evdev 2.8.1-1
xf86-input-synaptics 1.7.1-1
xf86-video-intel 2.21.15-1
xf86-video-vesa 2.3.2-3
xf86vidmodeproto 2.3.1-2
xfce4-appfinder 4.10.1-1
xfce4-mixer 4.10.0-2
xfce4-panel 4.10.1-1
xfce4-power-manager 1.2.0-4
xfce4-session 4.10.1-2
xfce4-settings 4.10.1-1
xfce4-terminal 0.6.2-1
xfconf 4.10.0-3
xfdesktop 4.10.2-1
xfsprogs 3.1.11-1
xfwm4 4.10.1-1
xfwm4-themes 4.10.0-1
xineramaproto 1.2.1-2
xkeyboard-config 2.9-2
xorg-bdftopcf 1.0.4-1
xorg-font-util 1.3.0-1
xorg-font-utils 7.6-3
xorg-fonts-alias 1.0.3-1
xorg-fonts-encodings 1.0.4-3
xorg-fonts-misc 1.0.1-2
xorg-iceauth 1.0.6-1
xorg-mkfontdir 1.0.7-1
xorg-mkfontscale 1.1.1-1
xorg-server 1.14.2-2
xorg-server-common 1.14.2-2
xorg-setxkbmap 1.3.0-1
xorg-xauth 1.0.7-1
xorg-xinit 1.3.2-3
xorg-xinput 1.6.0-1
xorg-xkbcomp 1.2.4-1
xorg-xrandr 1.4.1-1
xorg-xrdb 1.0.9-2
xorg-xset 1.2.3-1
xproto 7.0.24-1
xvidcore 1.3.2-1
xz 5.0.5-1
yajl 2.0.4-1
yaourt 1.3-1
zip 3.0-3
zlib 1.2.8-1
zsh 5.0.2-3
```

my svn configs looks like this:

~/.subversion/config:

```
cat ~/.subversion/config | grep -v "^#"

[auth]
store-passwords = yes
store-auth-creds = yes
password-stores = gnome-keyring
```

~/.subversion/servers

```
cat ~/.subversion/servers | grep -v "^#"

[global]
store-passwords = yes
store-plaintext-passwords = ask
```

I also played with `store-plaintext-passwords = no|yes` while not having a proper result! According to several Threads it should work with this configuration. Has Anyone an idea what I#m doing wrong or can try next?

Comment: What does `set | grep GNOME_KEYRING` report?

Comment: Are you following these instructions? http://support.wandisco.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/362/0/how-to-setup-encrypted-svn-password-storage-using-gnome-keyring-in-an-ssh-session

Comment: Also these instructions might be helpful: http://technicalprose.blogspot.com/2011/06/using-subversion-with-gnome-keyring.html

Comment: @cjm it reports `Binary file (standard input) matches`

Comment: @slm the first instructions are fore fedora. I saw them already, but cannot follow, because there is no `subversion-gnome` (and others) package to install. The second link is what I try next. I'll report back, if that works.

Comment: @RafaelT - OK. Please let us know how you make out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gnome-keyring-daemon` must be running for Subversion to store passwords in it. When the daemon starts, it emits two variables that need to be exported into your environment. So if it's already running, it might be easier to kill it and start over.

Start it up like this:

```
export $(nohup gnome-keyring-daemon 2>/dev/null)
```

The output that gets sent to `export` looks something like this:

```
GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET=/tmp/keyring-OpuUEI/socket
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=9256
```

Now when you execute a Subversion subcommand that requires it to contact the server, the client will prompt for your Subversion password first, then your Gnome keyring password. The keyring should stay unlocked for at least the duration of your login session (and maybe longer).

There are also some pointers on the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME_Keyring#Use_Without_GNOME) that may be Arch-specific, so take a look there if my suggestions don't work.

Comment: Question: Does this still work? The documentation in the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME_Keyring) nowadays says that GNOME_KEYRING_PID is not set anymore.

Answer (score 1):

## Install missing library

In a very similar setup I ran into the same problem. Starting the daemon manually as shown above did not solve the problem. After quite a while I discovered that the library that enables Gnome Keyring based authentication for Subversion was not installed. There was no error message displayed, so I did not notice it. I installed it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libsvn-auth-gnome-keyring
```

and it immediately worked.

Comment: For Fedora you need to install the package subversion-gnome.